# Refresh Cookie Claims in .Net Core 2.0 Identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, jwt

My web application is in .Net Core 2.0. Behind the scene I have .Net Core WebAPI as well. This WebAPI has JWT authentication with refresh token scenario. My web application is using same API to load data. I am using .Net Core Identity Cookie base authentication for my web application.

Question:

- In my web application, I am storing JWT in cookie using .Net Core Identity so that I can use same token in each API request. Here is how I am doing it,

> ```
> List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
>                         {
>                             new Claim("Token", responseData.AccessToken),
>                             new Claim("RefreshToken", responseData.RefreshToken),
>                             new Claim("Expires", Convert.ToString( responseData.Expires))
>                         };
>                         ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "cookie");
>                         ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
>                         await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
>                                 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
>                                 principal: principal);
> ```

- I have also implement logic to refresh token on desired time. BUT I am not sure how to update cookie claims when my token get refreshed so that next API can use updated token.

Please advice.

Comment: I'm looking for information on how ASP.NET Core refreshes the Cookie. I will watch this question. If I find an answer I'll get back.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41872895/2404452 this answer might be relevant to your problem.